# Adding things into an exsisting array in a json file, microDB

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to see if it's possible to add to an already created object on the ***MicroDB*** file.

I've tried using *`.push()`* but I'm having no luck.

The file has this object in already:

```
{
    "home": {
        "location": "walsall",
        "time": "12:00",
        "date": "12/12/17",
        "gym": "home",
        "players": ""
    }
}
```

File is a *`.json`*

I'm trying to add something into the `players` key when a user wants to join.

Any help? Also, how would one remove a `user name` from the `players` section aforementioned?

Edit:

Some code from my .js file

```
if (commandEX.toLowerCase() === "join") {
    var joinEX = message.content.split(' ')[2];
    if (joinEX === undefined) {
        return message.reply("**ERROR**: No gym entered, enter a gym to join.").then(m => m.delete(10000));
    }
    var removeTrigger = message.content.split(' ')[0];
    var findGym = message.content.slice(removeTrigger.length);
    findGym = findGym.slice(commandEX.length);
    findGym = findGym.slice(2);
    var commandFind = exRaidDB.data[findGym];
    memberEX = message.member.nickname;
    if (commandFind == undefined) {
        message.channel.send(`**ERROR**: No ex raid at that gym.`).then(m => m.delete(10000));
    } else {
        message.channel.send(`**Added ${memberEX} to the list, details below.** \n**EX Raid at** ${commandFind.gym} \n**Date**: ${commandFind.date} \n**Time**: ${commandFind.time} \n**Location**: ${commandFind.location}`);
        // this line is where the code needs to be for adding the $[message.member.nickname} into the "players" string.
    }
}
```

Comment: People are going to want to see some code, and a clear description of any errors.

Comment: The value of `players` is a *string*. If you want it to be an array then you have to assign an array to it first.

Comment: I've added some code in my op, sorry about the formatting though!

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged javascript, am I assuming correct you are using `Node.js`?

If it's the case, you could use `fs.writeFileSync(PATH_TO_JSON, JSON.stringify(newObj), 'utf8');` where `newObj` is the new object you want to store in the `.json`-file.

---

But instead of working with the file directly, you can use a simple wrapper like follows:

```
let
    fs = require('fs'),
    PATH_TO_JSON = '';

function readJson() {
    if (!fs.existsSync(PATH_TO_JSON)) {
        writeJson();
    }
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_JSON, 'utf8'));
}

function writeJson(obj = {}) {
    fs.writeFileSync(PATH_TO_JSON, JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf8');
}

function Ressource(path) {
    PATH_TO_JSON = path;
    this.data = readJson();
}

Ressource.prototype.set = function(obj) {
    this.data = obj;
};

Ressource.prototype.save = function() {
    writeJson(this.data);
};

module.exports = Ressource;
```

Comment: I've added some code in my op, sorry about the formatting though!

Comment: Will this work in the code I've posted? I don't actually see how that works 